# Horizontal animated scroll to div on click

Tags: jquery, css, accordion, scrollto

So, I need to make a horizontal accordion scroller which centers the opened div.
Code below will help you guys understand:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="product">
        <div class="product-title">
            <img src="http://goo.gl/PUr1TP">
        </div>
        <div class="product-all">
            <div style="width: 200px; background: red;"   >1</div>
            <div style="width: 100px; background: yellow;">2</div>
            <div style="width: 400px; background: pink;"  >3</div>
            <div style="width: 270px; background: blue;"  >4</div>
            <div style="width: 500px; background: aqua;"  >5</div>
            <div style="width: 100px; background: green;" >6</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
        <div class="product-title">
            <img src="https://goo.gl/hRJ3Dz">
        </div>
        <div class="product-all">
            <div style="width: 200px; background: red;"   >1</div>
            <div style="width: 100px; background: yellow;">2</div>
            <div style="width: 400px; background: pink;"  >3</div>
            <div style="width: 270px; background: blue;"  >4</div>
            <div style="width: 500px; background: aqua;"  >5</div>
            <div style="width: 100px; background: green;" >6</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
        <div class="product-title">
            <img src="https://goo.gl/vX3Aih">
        </div>
        <div class="product-all">
            <div style="width: 200px; background: red;"   >1</div>
            <div style="width: 100px; background: yellow;">2</div>
            <div style="width: 400px; background: pink;"  >3</div>
            <div style="width: 270px; background: blue;"  >4</div>
            <div style="width: 500px; background: aqua;"  >5</div>
            <div style="width: 100px; background: green;" >6</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
        <div class="product-title">
            <img src="http://goo.gl/rXt3kE">
        </div>
        <div class="product-all">
            <div style="width: 200px; background: red;"   >1</div>
            <div style="width: 100px; background: yellow;">2</div>
            <div style="width: 400px; background: pink;"  >3</div>
            <div style="width: 270px; background: blue;"  >4</div>
            <div style="width: 500px; background: aqua;"  >5</div>
            <div style="width: 100px; background: green;" >6</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
body, html {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #ccc;
}

html {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
       -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
            box-sizing: inherit;
}

.wrapper {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 200px 0 0 0;
}

.product, .product-title, .product-all, .product-all div {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.product-title img {
    height: 100%;
}

.product {
    position: relative;
}

.button {
    float: right;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border: 2px solid green;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $(".product-all").hide(100);
    $(".product-title").click(function() {
        $(".product-all").hide(500);
        $(this).parent().children(".product-all").show(500);

        var scrollTo = $(this).parent().children(".product-title").position().left;
        $('.wrapper').animate({
            'scrollLeft': scrollTo
        }, 800);
    });
});
```

Above is the code that I have tried, but scrolling seem to go to the very left of my container, not puts the "active" div in the left corner. Any ideas how to fix it? Thanks!

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/es_kaija/8Ls00qh3/)

Comment: Your main problem is that the var scrollTo contains 0. I think that is because each product is not positioned left. You need to find a way to find the relative position with respect to the wrapper element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed your problem and found a solution.

You didn't got the correct scrollTo. You trying to get the position of all children (with class product-title), but you need the position of the child that was clicked.

```
var scrollTo = $(this).parent().position().left;
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/jxv7641y/1/

Comment: I love you! Thank you so much!

Comment: One more comment: it still acts a little strange when the first one I open is one of the last ones. Any suggestions?

Comment: hmm... At first I thought this was because the accordion was still 'collapsing' to the left when the position is measured, but adding a delay, or removing the hiding animation didn't help. I suggest you try to give the divs a fixed width so you can predict the left position and then use logging to figure it out. You should post a different question if that doesn't help you.

Comment: Thank you for trying. Fixed width doesn't work because I won't know how many pictures will be added. Will sleep on this and try to figure it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

So, I figured it out!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $(".product-all").hide(100);
 $(".product-title").click(function() {

  $(".product-all").hide(500);
  $(this).parent().children(".product-all").show(500);

  //get the index of .product just clicked
  var i = 0;
  var piu = $(this).parent().index();
 //.wrapper
  var wrapper = $(this).parent().parent();
  var scroll_shit = 0;

  while (i < piu) {
   //get width of each .product-title, because the sum of all the previous .product-titles is the needed position
   product = wrapper.children().eq(i);
      scroll_shit = scroll_shit + product.children(".product-title").width();
      i++;
  }

  $('.wrapper').animate({
   'scrollLeft': scroll_shit
  }, 800);
 });

});
```

Comment: ah, great. That was the exact approuch I would try. What happend to the fiddle? It's unreachable at the moment....

Comment: @Jeroen i put the fiddle back. Thank you for your help, couldn't do it so fast without it :)